# Symbols in name suffixes to accept using wget

Tags: regex, download, wget

By using wget,
I noticed that if the name suffix to accept have a symbol like `"_"` this is not considered.

example:

```
wget -A "*my_name*" does not work (it does not get my_name.html although it exists)
wget -A "*name*" it works (it gets my_name.html)
```

How should I escape the symbol `"_"` in the name suffix option

Here is an example:

```
wget \
-A "*JavaScript\_Dynamically*" \
-e robots=off \
--mirror -E -k -p -np -nc --convert-links  \
--wait=5 -c  \
http://computerone.altervista.org
```

Comment: have you tried `"*my\-name*"`

Comment: @Alptugay, yes I did, but it does not match :(

Comment: @Alptugay, sorry I was wrong. the issue is about the `_` character not the `-`. I updated my question with an example.